# Best way to use Java module system in an educational setting?

Tags: java, module-info

I teach Java programming courses in a college setting. It would make sense to use the latest LTS version (Java 11) in the courses. We teach user interfaces using JavaFX. However, the combination of JavaFX plus the module system creates complications, especially for beginners.

In order to use JavaFX, one must have a `module-info.java` file which looks something like this:

```
module MyProject {
    // JavaFX must be able to start the application
    exports myPackage to javafx.graphics;

    // JavaFX modules that we require
    requires javafx.base;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.graphics;
}
```

Students normally use a single Java project for each course. In each course, they get many examples from me, and will write many more programs themselves. Each of these examples and exercises has it's own main class, and they are organized into many different packages.

The problem is that first `exports` statement: As far as I am aware, each statement applies only to a single package, no wildcards are possible, and sub-packages are not included. Hence, if we have a Java project with 50 different packages, `module-info.java` will contain fifty `exports` statements. This is a mess.

Maybe this seems minor, but it is yet another hurdle for people just learning to program. Have I overlooked some way to generalize `exports` to cover multiple packages? Alternatively, does anyone have a good suggestion on ways to simplify this for my students?

Comment: you might want to change the title of the question to better reflect the question content. in the education context, it's better to use the latest available version (so that by the time the students graduate, the versions will still be relevant).

Comment: Ok, I changed the title to reflect the fact that this is mainly about the Java module system.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful but I started a project of modules in
Github. Since your question wasn't answered I'll ask if you found good
ways to do this.

My Setting is in Github.
Pure Java, with a GitHub action to helps to create the Jars.

> https://github.com/disparter/java-snippets
>
> Since I use only one repository, it is easy to share even with many
> modules.
> I usually use Discord to discuss and some relevant content I put in a dev notes file but it is in Portuguese.

In my case, I do 2 things.

1. Create a simple snippet to demonstrate some arguments.
2. Create a simple module to be able to demonstrate if any a good Object Orientation practice.

OBS

> Think in java modules for small pieces. If you want to handle bigger projects is nice to use Gradle or Maven for those. It is interesting in an educational way when dependency problems happen. If you think there are too many modules to import, you can create a module that can be used as a Layer to help import common things.

Comment: The question is about how to use `exports`. This answer doesn't address the question.

Comment: I think different. Yeah you cant use wildcards for the export but when you start to use templates like the one I put in can improve group productivity.